# Database Toll Layout

Tags: mysql, database

My Problem ist i get duplicated primary key on Tarife , so my question how should I change the layout without getting duplicate prime ?

to the db: i have some routes "from, to" and they have a certain distance to each other, and there are different highways -> autobahn and they have 2 typs some of then are flat -> eben or mountainous -> berg, and than you have to differentiate between the five classes, so i got 27 Highways * 2 Typs * 5 classes.
i hope u can help me :)
i want this in mysql

here some picture of the tables

https://i.stack.imgur.com/knuv3.jpg
[http://imgur.com/XiveTv9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVmRu.jpg)

Comment: What is the structure of your tables? Screenshots from excel-like-programs don't really help. What query is giving you an error?

Comment: get error while inserting into tarife table , i know what my problem is  but i don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your screenshots I assume that `AutobahnID` and `typID` are primary keys. If so, you would need to change the structure of your `Tarif` table a bit. There are many ways to do this, but here I what I would do:

`id` -> An auto-incrementing primary key of type int.

`autobahn_id` -> A foreign key which references id of the Autobahn table.

`typ_id` -> A foreign key which references the id of the Typ table.

`klasse_id` -> A foreign key which references the id of the Klasse table.

Foreign keys are ideal for referencing to rows in other tables. I suggest reading about Foreign Keys [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). Note that not all database engines support Foreign Keys, such as MyISAM. InnoDB is one of the engines that support Foreign Keys.

I would suggest dropping all primary keys first from your Tarif table and then add the Foreign Keys like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Tarif ADD CONSTRAINT FK_autobahn_id FOREIGN KEY (autobahn_id) REFERENCES Autobahn(ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```